# Problema objeto Hibernate!

Tags: java, hibernate, object

Buenas a todos!!
Tengo un problema con los objetos en Hibernate.

Este es el método que utilizo para extraer el objeto:

```
public Moto loadMotoId(SessionFactory SessionBuilder, int idMoto) {
    Session conexion = SessionBuilder.openSession();

    Query q = conexion.createQuery("FROM Moto WHERE id = :_nid");
    q.setParameter("_nid", idMoto);

    List listMotos = q.list();

    Moto moto = new Moto();

    if (!listMotos.isEmpty()) {
        moto = (Moto) listMotos.get(0);
    } else {
        listMotos = null;
    }
    conexion.close();

    return moto;
}
```

Este es parte el código del servlet:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Operaciones objop = new Operaciones();    
Moto moto=objop.loadMotoId(SessionBuilder, idMoto);
session.setAttribute("moto", moto);
```

Cuando quiero mostrar los diferentes atributos del objeto en el jsp, los campos de id relacionados con otras tablas no me los muestra, por ejemplo:

Recojo el objeto guardado previamente en el servlet en la variable session:

```
<%
Moto moto = (Moto) session.getAttribute("moto");
%>
```

Parte de código html de una tabla dónde quiero mostrar el tipo de moto del objeto moto, que es una clave fóranea a otra tabla en mi bbdd:

```
<td><%=moto.getTipoMoto().getNombre()%></td>
```

Pues en esa línea me da error, el resto de campos me los muestra correctamente excepto los que son claves fóraneas a otras tablas y no sé por qué es. A ver si me podéis echar un cable. Gracias!!

Añado la clase Moto aquí:

```
package POJO;
// Generated 30-ene-2018 13:25:55 by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * Moto generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Moto  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private Integer id;
 private Diseno diseno;
 private TipoMoto tipoMoto;
 private String marca;
 private String modelo;
 private int cilindrada;
 private int caballos;
 private float aceleracion;
 private float consumo;
 private float velocidadMax;
 private float precioBase;
 private String imagen;
 private int stock;
 private Set reservas = new HashSet(0);

public Moto() {
}


public Moto(Diseno diseno, TipoMoto tipoMoto, String marca, String modelo, int cilindrada, int caballos, float aceleracion, float consumo, float velocidadMax, float precioBase, String imagen, int stock) {
    this.diseno = diseno;
    this.tipoMoto = tipoMoto;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
    this.caballos = caballos;
    this.aceleracion = aceleracion;
    this.consumo = consumo;
    this.velocidadMax = velocidadMax;
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
    this.imagen = imagen;
    this.stock = stock;
}
public Moto(Diseno diseno, TipoMoto tipoMoto, String marca, String modelo, int cilindrada, int caballos, float aceleracion, float consumo, float velocidadMax, float precioBase, String imagen, int stock, Set reservas) {
   this.diseno = diseno;
   this.tipoMoto = tipoMoto;
   this.marca = marca;
   this.modelo = modelo;
   this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
   this.caballos = caballos;
   this.aceleracion = aceleracion;
   this.consumo = consumo;
   this.velocidadMax = velocidadMax;
   this.precioBase = precioBase;
   this.imagen = imagen;
   this.stock = stock;
   this.reservas = reservas;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Diseno getDiseno() {
    return this.diseno;
}

public void setDiseno(Diseno diseno) {
    this.diseno = diseno;
}
public TipoMoto getTipoMoto() {
    return this.tipoMoto;
}

public void setTipoMoto(TipoMoto tipoMoto) {
    this.tipoMoto = tipoMoto;
}
public String getMarca() {
    return this.marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}
public String getModelo() {
    return this.modelo;
}

public void setModelo(String modelo) {
    this.modelo = modelo;
}
public int getCilindrada() {
    return this.cilindrada;
}

public void setCilindrada(int cilindrada) {
    this.cilindrada = cilindrada;
}
public int getCaballos() {
    return this.caballos;
}

public void setCaballos(int caballos) {
    this.caballos = caballos;
}
public float getAceleracion() {
    return this.aceleracion;
}

public void setAceleracion(float aceleracion) {
    this.aceleracion = aceleracion;
}
public float getConsumo() {
    return this.consumo;
}

public void setConsumo(float consumo) {
    this.consumo = consumo;
}
public float getVelocidadMax() {
    return this.velocidadMax;
}

public void setVelocidadMax(float velocidadMax) {
    this.velocidadMax = velocidadMax;
}
public float getPrecioBase() {
    return this.precioBase;
}

public void setPrecioBase(float precioBase) {
    this.precioBase = precioBase;
}
public String getImagen() {
    return this.imagen;
}

public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
}
public int getStock() {
    return this.stock;
}

public void setStock(int stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}
public Set getReservas() {
    return this.reservas;
}

public void setReservas(Set reservas) {
    this.reservas = reservas;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente el problema que tienes seguramente sea el siguiente escenario:

1. Pides a Hibernate una sesión.
2. Pides a la sesión una Moto.
3. Hibernate crea una instancia de Moto haciendo una consulta SQL a la base de datos. Dicha instancia de Moto apunta a otros elementos que habría que recuperar de otras tablas, pero en lugar de realizar todas esas consultas, Hibernate para aquí porque está configurado para trabajar en modo "`FetchType.LAZY`" (tipo de obtención "PEREZOSO"). En lugar de traerte esos objetos, crea otros especiales para detectar cuándo los necesitas y obtenerlos más tarde.
4. Cierras la sesión (que no conexión, ahí te estás liando un poco)
5. Intentas obtener en tu JSP los valores que no han sido obtenidos. Hibernate intenta pedirlos pero la sesión ha sido cerrada, con lo que no puede obtenerlos y lanza un fallo "LazyInitializationException".

Soluciones:

1. Usar `FetchType.EAGER` para obtener esos datos siempre al pedir un objeto Moto a la base de datos.
2. Decirle a Hibernate que puede obtener esos datos fuera de una transacción, que no es problema obtenerlos después, añadiendo la opción `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans = true` a la configuración de tu conexión.

La primera solución tiene dos formas de implementarse:

La *moderna*, es decir, usando anotaciones:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "tipo_moto_id") //columna de la tabla moto que hace de clave foránea
private TipoMoto tipoMoto;
```

La clásica, usando un fichero hbm.xml:

```
<many-to-one name="tipoMoto" class="POJO.TipoMoto" lazy="false">
    <column name="tipo_moto_id" />
</many-to-one>
```

Consejo extra, fuera del contexto de la pregunta: Evita usar scriptlets en un JSP, ¡son un cáncer!

Comment: Cómo uso FetchType.EAGER?? Dónde debo configurarlo? Estoy usando Netbeans. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Añade el código de la clase Moto y podré explicar con más detalle lo que hay que hacer.

Comment: Ya lo tienes. Por cierto, tengo que añadir alguna librería en concreto para ello? Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!

Comment: Perdona, es que soy nuevo por aquí como habrás notado, jeje. No se si ahora lo he hecho bien. Disculpa y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con lo que necesitas