# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session Solved

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

si tengo una clase "Ciudad" y una "Persona" cada una con sus atributos pero Hibernate en la clase "Persona" en lugar de **int** **IdCiudad**  trabaja con **Ciudad getCiudad** en el get y set y mientras que agrega un atributo de tipo **Set<*Persona*> Persona** a la clase "Ciudad", ¿cómo agrego ciudad a una persona si tengo el **id** de la ciudad? no ingresaré `Ciudad`, y ¿cómo recivo de un **ajax** en formato **json** de la lista de Ciudades sin que me intente cargar la lista de `Personas` que no lo necesito y evitar que salga **org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session Solved**

**DB 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estructura**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AppConfig**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.config;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewResolverRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
     public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

          InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
          viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
          viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
          viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
          registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
     }

     @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
     }

     @Override
     public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer matcher) {
          matcher.setUseRegisteredSuffixPatternMatch(true);
     }
}
```

**AppInitializer**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.config;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
          return new Class[]{AppConfig.class};
     }

     @Override
     protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
          return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected String[] getServletMappings() {
          return new String[]{"/"};
     }

     @Override
     protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
          boolean done = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound", "true"); // -> true
          boolean dona = registration.setInitParameter("throwExceptionIfIllegalState", "true");
          if (!done || !dona) {
               throw new RuntimeException();
          }
     }
}
```

**js.js**

```js
function p(l) {
     $("#tabla tr").slice(1).remove();
     for (var i = 0; i < l.l.length; i++) {
          $("#tabla").append("<tr><th>" + l.l[i].nombrePersona + "</th><th>" + l.l[i].apellidoPersona + "</th><th>" + l.l[i].ciudad + "</th></tr>");
     }
}
function c(l) {
     $("#ciudad option").remove();
     for (var i = 0; i < l.l.length; i++) {
          $("#ciudad").append("<option value='" + l.l[i].idCiudad + "'>" + l.l[i].nombreCiudad + "</option>");
     }
}
function listar() {
     $.ajax({
          url: "listPersonas",
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(r) {
               p(r);
          }
     });
}
function listarCiudad() {
     $.ajax({
          url: "ciudades",
          type: 'GET',
          success: function(r) {
               c(r);
          }
     });
}
listarCiudad();

// en lugar de "ciudad: c " deberia ir " idCiudad: c " como unico valor, no un objeto de tipo Ciudad
function add() {
     var np = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
     var ap = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
     var c = document.getElementById("ciudad").value;
     $.ajax({
          url: "addPersonas",
          type: 'GET',
          data: {nombrePersona: np, apellidoPersona: ap, ciudad: c},
          success: function(r) {
               p(r);
          }
     });
}
```

**index.jsp**

**vistas.java**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.control;

import com.dao.CiudadDao;
import com.dao.PersonaDao;
import com.model.Persona;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
@Controller
public class vistas {

     @RequestMapping("/")
     public String index() {
          return "index";
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/ciudades", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application/json")
     public @ResponseBody
     Map<String, Object> ciudades() {
          Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
          CiudadDao cd = new CiudadDao();
          List l = cd.getAll();
          map.put("l", l);
          return map;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/listPersonas", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application/json")
     public @ResponseBody
     Map<String, Object> listPersonas() {
          Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
          PersonaDao cd = new PersonaDao();
          List l = cd.getAll();
          map.put("l", l);
          return map;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value = "/addPersonas", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}, produces = "application/json")
     public @ResponseBody
     Map<String, Object> addPersonas(Persona p) {
          Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
          PersonaDao cd = new PersonaDao();
          cd.create(p);
          List l = cd.getAll();
          map.put("l", l);
          return map;
     }
}
```

**Ciudad.java**

```html
package com.model;
// Generated 14/02/2018 06:51:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Ciudad generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="Ciudad"
    ,catalog="Ciudadanos"
)
public class Ciudad  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idCiudad;
     private String nombreCiudad;
     private Set<Persona> personas = new HashSet<Persona>(0);

    public Ciudad() {
    }

 
    public Ciudad(String nombreCiudad) {
        this.nombreCiudad = nombreCiudad;
    }
    public Ciudad(String nombreCiudad, Set<Persona> personas) {
       this.nombreCiudad = nombreCiudad;
       this.personas = personas;
    }
   
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    
    @Column(name="idCiudad", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdCiudad() {
        return this.idCiudad;
    }
    
    public void setIdCiudad(Integer idCiudad) {
        this.idCiudad = idCiudad;
    }

    
    @Column(name="Nombre_Ciudad", nullable=false, length=25)
    public String getNombreCiudad() {
        return this.nombreCiudad;
    }
    
    public void setNombreCiudad(String nombreCiudad) {
        this.nombreCiudad = nombreCiudad;
    }

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="ciudad")
    public Set<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return this.personas;
    }
    
    public void setPersonas(Set<Persona> personas) {
        this.personas = personas;
    }




}
```

**Persona.java**

```html
package com.model;
// Generated 14/02/2018 06:51:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * Persona generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="Persona"
    ,catalog="Ciudadanos"
)
public class Persona  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private Integer idPersona;
     private Ciudad ciudad;
     private String nombrePersona;
     private String apellidoPersona;

    public Persona() {
    }

    public Persona(Ciudad ciudad, String nombrePersona, String apellidoPersona) {
       this.ciudad = ciudad;
       this.nombrePersona = nombrePersona;
       this.apellidoPersona = apellidoPersona;
    }
   
     @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=IDENTITY)

    
    @Column(name="idPersona", unique=true, nullable=false)
    public Integer getIdPersona() {
        return this.idPersona;
    }
    
    public void setIdPersona(Integer idPersona) {
        this.idPersona = idPersona;
    }

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="idCiudad", nullable=false)
    public Ciudad getCiudad() {
        return this.ciudad;
    }
    
    public void setCiudad(Ciudad ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    
    @Column(name="Nombre_persona", nullable=false, length=25)
    public String getNombrePersona() {
        return this.nombrePersona;
    }
    
    public void setNombrePersona(String nombrePersona) {
        this.nombrePersona = nombrePersona;
    }

    
    @Column(name="Apellido_Persona", nullable=false, length=25)
    public String getApellidoPersona() {
        return this.apellidoPersona;
    }
    
    public void setApellidoPersona(String apellidoPersona) {
        this.apellidoPersona = apellidoPersona;
    }




}
```

**CiudadDao.java**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dao;

import com.model.Ciudad;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
public class CiudadDao {

     public List<Ciudad> getAll() {
          List<Ciudad> lst = new ArrayList();
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               lst = s.createCriteria(Ciudad.class).list();
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return lst;
     }

     public Ciudad getCiudad(int id) {
          Ciudad lst = new Ciudad();
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               lst = (Ciudad) s.createCriteria(Ciudad.class)
                       .add(Restrictions.eq("idCiudad", id))
                       .uniqueResult();
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return lst;
     }

     public void create(Ciudad d) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.save(d);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }

     public void remove(Ciudad d) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.delete(d);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }

     public void edit(Ciudad p) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.update(p);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }
}
```

**PersonaDao.java**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dao;

import com.model.Persona;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

/**
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
public class PersonaDao {

     public List<Persona> getAll() {
          List<Persona> lst = new ArrayList();
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               lst = s.createCriteria(Persona.class).list();
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return lst;
     }

     public Persona getPersona(int id) {
          Persona lst = new Persona();
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               lst = (Persona) s.createCriteria(Persona.class)
                       .add(Restrictions.eq("idPersona", id))
                       .uniqueResult();
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return lst;
     }

     public void create(Persona d) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.save(d);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }

     public void remove(Persona d) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.delete(d);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }

     public void edit(Persona p) {
          Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          try {
               s.beginTransaction();
               s.update(p);
               s.getTransaction().commit();
          } catch (Exception e) {
               s.getTransaction().rollback();
          }
     }
}
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```html
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.dao;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

/**
 * Hibernate Utility class with a convenient method to get Session Factory object.
 *
 * @author ASUS
 */
public class HibernateUtil {

     private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     static {
          try {
               // Create the SessionFactory from standard (hibernate.cfg.xml)
               // config file.
               sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
               // Log the exception.
               System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
               throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
          }
     }

     public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
          return sessionFactory;
     }
}
```

**Ciudad.hbm.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14/02/2018 06:51:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.model.Ciudad" table="Ciudad" catalog="Ciudadanos" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idCiudad" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idCiudad" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="nombreCiudad" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre_Ciudad" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="personas" table="Persona" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="idCiudad" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.model.Persona" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Persona.hbm.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 14/02/2018 06:51:39 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.model.Persona" table="Persona" catalog="Ciudadanos" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idPersona" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="idPersona" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="ciudad" class="com.model.Ciudad" fetch="select">
            <column name="idCiudad" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="nombrePersona" type="string">
            <column name="Nombre_persona" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="apellidoPersona" type="string">
            <column name="Apellido_Persona" length="25" not-null="true" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**hibernate.revenge.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
     <schema-selection match-catalog="Ciudadanos"/>
     <table-filter match-name="Ciudad"/>
     <table-filter match-name="Persona"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Ciudadanos?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">myuser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mypassword</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping resource="com/model/Ciudad.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/model/Persona.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**resultado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu código para que puedas recibir ayuda, sino es difícil. Saludos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Problema objeto Hibernate!](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135479/problema-objeto-hibernate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Ciudad.java

cambia:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="ciudad")
public Set<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return this.personas;
}
```

por:

```
@JsonIgnore //De la libreria jackson
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="ciudad")
public Set<Persona> getPersonas() {
        return this.personas;
}
```

Y en Persona.Java

```
@JoinColumn(name="idCiudad", nullable=false)
public Ciudad getCiudad() {
    return this.ciudad;
}
```

por:

```
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name="idCiudad", nullable=false)
public Ciudad getCiudad() {
    return this.ciudad;
}
```

De esta manera ya no te marcara ese error, lo que sucede es que si no se ignoran esos campos obtendrías un objeto anidado infinito, porque por default va y busca llenar la la lista de personas de "x" ciudad y a cada una de esas personas le va a poner los datos de la ciudad y así seguiria eternamente por eso java manda la excepcion

Comment: Excelente, gracias